# vue JS - Append data (strings) to a placeholder

Tags: vue.js

I am a absolut beginner with vue.js. So I did a little app for learning. But I stuck a little bit with append-Data to a placeholder, if that is the right term, for

> {{ message1 }}

Here is my code:

```
<script>
Vue.createApp({
data() {
  return {
  bheight: '',
  bwidth: '',
  
}
},
methods: {
  domath(event) {
    alert(`Hello!`)
    
    
  }
}
}).mount('#app')
</script>
```

The "domath" method is triggred by a button. That work (the allert show up). I have this placeholder "message1. {{ message1 }}

What I want is this: If the button is clicked, I want the data from "bheight" and "bwidth" appends to the placeholder {{ message1 }}

Later I want to do a math with this both variables. And append the result in the placeholder.

Id do not figured out how I can to this. Can some help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an additional variable:

```
data() {
  return {
    bheight: '',
    bwidth: '',
    message1: ''
 }
```

And then:

```
domath(event) {
   this.message1 += this.bwidth + ', ' + this.bheight;

}
```

Using `this` is crucial iin this context.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Add computed Property

```
computed: {
   placeholder() {
      return this.errors.has('end_date') ? 'Your placeholder text' : ''
   }
}
```

Next Steps:

Bind to your computed placeholder property with v-bind:placeholder="placeholder"